# Error on Oracle Apex Application

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have inherited a Oracle Apex project and I am a newbie to apex development.

My work is primarily on WebSphere server but I need the Oracle Apex application on my machine.
The setup of my development machine is

1. Oracle 11G enterprise version
2. Tomcat for Apex
3. Websphere Application Server 8.5

There is a strange issue happening. When the apex login page is run it gives an error message "Error    Error processing request. ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error"

But the moment I run my WebSphere application the apex application also starts running properly. Both the Apex application and WebSphere application point to the same database. I connect from my Websphere application using Oracle thin driver.

The apex team says that there is no dependency on the WAS application server. 
I suspect something gets started when I run my Websphere application which helps the apex application to start working properly. I am not able to figure out what causes everything in Apex to run properly when the  Websphere application starts.

How can I debug what is going wrong when my apex application is running independently. I have asked the apex team to help me out in debugging. My expectation is that when the apex application it must be logging the error message in some logfile or table. Any pointers on debugging will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged into the Apex Application Builder, and then you visit your login page, the Apex Developer Toolbar should become visible at the bottom of the screen.
On this toolbar, click the Debug button to start debugging. After that, try to log in, and then click View Debug. Maybe you can find some more information there.